# Angular2 select failed to set the default Value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My select department template code looks like,

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Location</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" *ngIf="locations" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Select A Location" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedLocation"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        <option *ngFor="let loc of locations"
          [ngValue]="loc">
          {{loc.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <span *ngIf="!selectedLocation" class="help-block text-danger">
        You must select one Location.
    </span>
  </div>
```

This code is reponsible for getting the locations from server. I can manage to list these locations once the `select` dropdown is clicked.

`select.ts`

```
private selectedLocation: any = null;

ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm();
    this.getLocations();
  }

setDefaultTypeAndLocation() {    
    for (let location of this.locations) {
      if (location.name === this.vehicle.location) {
        this.selectedLocation = location;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.vehicle);
    if (this.vehicle.type.key !== '' && this.vehicle.location) {
      this.setDefaultTypeAndLocation();
    }
    this.buildForm();
  }

getLocations() {
    this.locations = this.locationsService.locations;
    if (!this.locations) {
      this.locationsService.list()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.locations = data;
          },
          error => {
            console.log('err in vehicle form getLocations method');
          }
        );
    } else {
    }
  }
```

On clicking the edit button on the parent component, corresponding `vehicle` object is passed to the child component which thereby initiates the `ngOnChanges` method.

See, this  `this.setDefaultTypeAndLocation();` invokes method `setDefaultTypeAndLocation()` which was used to set the default Location (`this.selectedLocation = location;`).

From this point, I properly updated the `this.selectedLocation` value. But on the View, the location I set previously wasn't shown as default Location.

Comment: maybe, just maybe, ngIf is problem here. You are first rendering form, then check if locations is populated, then rendering select button.

With that case you are creating two different scopes.Try to use [hidden] property. `<div class="custom" [hidden]="!locations">`

Answer (score 0):

<del>Maybe your are not showing all code, but I don't see you ever calling the `getLocations()` method. This means that `this.locations` will always be an empty list, so no location can be set.</del>

**edit:**

Instead of initializing your locations in `ngOnInit`, change your `getLocations` method to update locations when needed. Initializing in in `ngOnInit` won't work, since `ngOnChanges` is called BEFORE `ngOnInit` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

See this code example:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    //do not initialize locations here
  }

  setDefaultTypeAndLocation() {
    //change this.location to this.getLocations()
    for (let location of this.getLocations()) { 
      if (location.name === this.vehicle.location) {
        this.selectedLocation = location;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  getLocations() {
    // Add this check
    if (this.locations && this.locations.length > 0) return this.locations;

    this.locations = this.locationsService.locations;
    if (!this.locations) {
      this.locationsService.list()
        .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.locations = data;
        },
        error => {
          console.log('err in vehicle form getLocations method');
        }
        );
    } else {
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have called `this.getLocations();` in OnInit.. I have no problem with listing locations but I have problem with setting a default location.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that ngOnChanges is actually called BEFORE ngOnInit. Meaning the location list might not be initialized the first time you call ngOnChanges.

See docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: so from where this `getLocations()` is being called? Note that one each time, edit button on parent comp is clicked `ngOnchanges` getting called but `ngOnInit` won't which would be called only during the initialisation process.

Comment: getLocations() is being called in the for-loop in setDefaultTypeAndLocation(). So indirectly it's being called every time ngOnChange is called, which in turn means every time you press Edit on your parent component.

See my updated answer.